# How to send notification with image to IOS and android in PHP

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Laravel app in which I use some code to send FCM to send notification to IOS and Android, but now I need to include and image in the notification.
the code I am using now is as below

```
$fcmUrl =   'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
        $notification = [
            'body' => 'Message',
            'title'=>'title',
            'sound' => true,
            'priority' => "high",
            'vibration'=>true,
            'sound'=> "Enabled",
            'badge'=>4,
            'id'=>2
            ];

        $extraNotificationData = ['one'=>1,'two'=>2];
      
        $fcmNotification = [
            //'registration_ids' => json_encode($token,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT), //multple token array
            'to' => $this->token, //single token
            'data' => $extraNotificationData,
            'notification' => $notification
        ];

        $headers = [
            'Authorization: key=Server_key',
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        ];

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fcmUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fcmNotification));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: try to add the image key in notification array  
ref -https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-image

Comment: $notification = [
            'body' => 'Message',
            'title'=>'title',
            'sound' => true,
            'priority' => "high",
            'vibration'=>true,
            'sound'=> "Enabled",
            'badge'=>4,
            'id'=>2,
            'image'=>image_url
            ];

Comment: yes, I added it as below, but no use

Comment: `$notification = [
            'body' => $this->message,
            'title'=>'Spatime',
            'sound' => true,
            'priority' => "high",
            'vibration'=>true,
            'sound'=> "Enabled",
            'badge'=>4,
            'id'=>2,
            'image' => 'https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mysitemyway/clean-3d/256/glossy-3d-blue-web-icon.png',
            ];`